libp2p share metadata in peer:discover event
The goal is to add a new metadata field available to all other peers during the peer:discovery event. I want to use peerStore.merge, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.
Has anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any advice would be greatly appreciated also in other languages.. unfortunately, the library's documentation is not very clear on these details
Here am trying at peer creation of my peer instance(peerId), want share meta info with other peers, written in javascript/nodejs:
const meta = {custom: {my: 'field'}} ///a new custom object for metadata
const metaBin = new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(meta));  //encode in binary

await libp2p.peerStore.merge(peerId, {
    metadata: {
      meta: metaBin
    }
})

After running this code, I expect the new metadata field to be visible to other peers during the peer:discovery event, but it doesn't seem to be propagated.
Running in other peers this code:

libp2p.addEventListener('peer:discovery', async e => {
  const peer = e.detail;
  const peerInfo = await libp2p.peerStore.get(peer.id);
  console.log('peerInfo:',peerInfo)

peerInfo contains an empty Map(0) metadata, this is console.log outout:
peerInfo: {
  addresses: [],
  protocols: [],
  metadata: Map(0) {},
  tags: Map(1) { 'bootstrap' => { value: 50, expiry: 1718117050637n } },
  id: PeerId(QmckJMAv2BfATF1FjcqPndJHoWKbqACNoEvmsWN8unxyiG),
  peerRecordEnvelope: undefined
}

